# Looping through and modify each element of a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given a dataset like this

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'description': ["abcd","efgh","ijkl"], 'code': ["A","K","Z"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


  description   code
0   abcd          A
1   efgh          K
2   ijkl          Z
```

I'm aiming at getting this

```
   description  code
0   "abcd"        A
1   "efgh"        K
2   "ijkl"        Z
```

this code *just prints* out what I'm aiming at

```
for row in df["description"]:   #accessing to each row
    print(f'"{row}"')           #"modifying" each row
```

and this is what generates

```
"abcd"
"efgh"
"ijkl"
```

I was trying to set something like this but it's not correct

```
rows = df.shape[0]
i = 0
while i < rows:
     f'"{df.loc[i,"description"]}"'
#wrong
```

or something like

```
df1["description"]=df1["description"].apply(lambda ??
```

Comment: create a sample dataframe and an expected output for better understanding (and so that we can test with it with the same logic)

Comment: ok I'll add it now

Comment: Read the Pandas docs. Why do you want the quotes around those elements in the first place?

Comment: because when I export the dataset to a .csv file the quotes are not added back to the elements of the first row which have commas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this simply:

```py
df['description1'] = '"'+ df['description'] + '"'
df

  description code description1
0        abcd    A       "abcd"
1        efgh    K       "efgh"
2        ijkl    Z       "ijkl"
```

Answer (score 0):

With row iteration, you can do something like that:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
  new_val = something
  if <condition>:
    new_val = something_else
  df.at[i,'description'] = new_val
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your while loop, it would look like this:

```
rows = df.shape[0]
i = 0
while i < rows:
    df.iloc[i,:]['description'] = '"' + df.iloc[i,:]['description'] + '"'
    i = i+1
```